# php mysqli ultimo registro

Tags: php, classes

Tenho uma pagina que faz conexão atraves de classe do mysqli do modo abaixo:

```
# include da classe

class connectionClass extends mysqli{
    public $host="localhost",$dbname="banco",$dbpass="",$dbuser="susus";
    public $con;

    public function __construct() {
        if($this->connect($this->host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname)){}
        else
    {
        return "<h1>Erro de conexão/h1>";
    }
}
}
```

pagina onde é chama a classe

```
require_once 'connectionClass.php';

class webcamClass extends connectionClass{

    $query  =   "INSERT INTO vis_pres_path_foto (fk_id_user_sistema,vis_pres_path_foto_image) ";
    $query  .=  "VALUES('$id_user','$image') ";
    $result =   $this->query($query);
}
```

Como eu faço depois do `insert` acima retornar o último
`id` da tabela após o `insert` no PDO eu uso `$ultimo = $conn->lastInsertId();`
mas, para esse caso não funciona.

Comment: primeiro repare que seu if e else estão dentro da mesma chave, conserte isso no seu código pois a sintaxe correta é if { parametros } else { parametros }  e não da forma como você indica if{ parametros ... else {} {

Comment: $this->insert_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `mysqli` possui o `int $insert_id`, que retorna o ultimo id gerado pelo mysql, veja como usar em sua situação:

```
    $query  =   "INSERT INTO vis_pres_path_foto (fk_id_user_sistema,vis_pres_path_foto_image) ";
    $query  .=  "VALUES('$id_user','$image') ";
    $result =   $this->query($query);
    $ultimoId = $this->insert_id;
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, agora funcionou, era isso que eu estava precisando.
Ele retorna o ultimo id inserido na tabela.

Answer (score 1):

depois de corrigir a sintaxe do seu código você pode criar uma função como essa

```
<?php
/*
 * Description of LastId
 *
 * @author Adriano Back
 */
class LastId {

private $id;

    public function __construct(){
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DBURI,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_error())
        {
            exit("Falha de Conexão: <br />" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $query = "SELECT id FROM suatabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or 
                die(mysqli_error($conn) . " Falha de Consulta " . $query);


        $id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        foreach($id as $last_id){
            $this->id = $last_id['id'];
        }    
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

    public function getLastId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

depois você instancia assim

```
$id = new LastId();
$last_id = $id->getLastId();
```

Comment: Ai foi no POG em kk

Comment: hehe to acostumado com pdo nem lembrava direito como fazia em mysqli

Comment: mas nem sei o que signigica POG